# How to set boolean value in curl command used bash script

Tags: bash, json

I need set into variable true/false value and send him into json with `curl` command:

```
name=$1
sx=$2

`curl -d '{"name":"'"$name"'", "sex":true}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/setacc`
```

Variable `sx` accepts the value `male` or `female` how to set the appropriate boolean value into `sex` variable?

Comment: Which one is the _true_ sex? Male or female? Maybe there are other values?

Comment: @PerlDuck it is do not matter. It is can be `0` - true, or `1` - false

Comment: The USA is awake and they're a bunch of puritans.  A bit later New Zealand and Australia will wake up and they've got a great sense of humour, so they'll give you a sympathy **+1** as well.

Comment: Naah, never mind! I think the question was just downvoted because of the mixture of male/female, true/false, and 0/1.

Comment: Anyone trying to use this web API has to remember which of two arbitrary labels was assigned to `male` and `female`, instead of just using `male` and `female`. I'm sure that'll never get confusing. Good on you for trying to make it a little more usable from your tool.

Comment: `"sex":file-not-found`

Comment: @NicHartley, it is do not matter. I need know, how to set value in BOOLEAN variable. I know how to set string value! - `"name":"'"$name"'"` But that not working with BOOLEAN

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, where are you search a file?

Comment: Sorry that's meant to be a [humorous third boolean value: `true`, `false`, `file-not-found`](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a variable for the whole JSON string and building it piece wise can make the quoting less cumbersome and make the `curl` command line more readable and easier to maintain even though the overall code is much more verbose.

Building the string is done here using the string self concatenation operator `+=`. Note that in `json_string+=$name`, for example, no quoting is necessary since there's no word splitting being performed and no special characters are present on the right hand side.

You can use an associative array to look up the value you want based on the provided key. Here I'm assigning the pairs individually. Below I'll show how to do them in one assignment.

```
name=$1
sx=$2

declare -A sexes
sexes[male]=false
sexes[female]=true

json_string='{"name":"'
json_string+=$name
json_string+='", "sex":'
json_string+=${sexes[$sx]}
json_string+='}'

curl -d "$json_string" " -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/setacc
```

You can break the JSON up even more to make it look a little more structured in the code (the resulting string contents will still be a single-line string). Ideally, if you're using more complicated JSON than this you should use a purpose built JSON tool for building the structure.

Here's how you can make the associative array declaration and assignment all at once. The first example is on one line and the second is on multiple lines - again for improved readability and maintainability.

```
declare -A sexes='([female]="true" [male]="false")'

declare -A sexes='(
    [female]="true"
    [male]="false"
)'
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to map the string `male` to either `true` or `false` (depending on your needs) and `female` to some other value is a simple `if…then…else` clause. The trick is the quoting but you already got that with the `$name` variable. So:

```
if [ "$sx" = "male" ]; then
    sex="true";     # or whatever you consider male sex to be
else
    sex="false";    # just the opposite, see above
fi

curl -d '{"name":"'"$name"'", "sex":'$sex'}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/setacc
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case you use json and can use text "true" and text "false".

You need add to bash script logic:

```
sex="false"
if [ "$sx" = "male" ]; then
  sex="true"
fi
```

then run curl command with `... {"name":"'"$name"'", "sex":\"$sex\"} ...` or just `... {"name":"'"$name"'", "sex":$sex} ...`

Test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sx="male"

sex="false"
if [ "$sx" = "male" ]; then
  sex="true"
fi

echo \"$sex\"
```